# Special function keys are mixed up on my Macbook Pro

Tags: keyboard, macbook-pro, function-keys

I recently sent my Macbook Pro (late 2008 model) to get a replaced logic board and top cover. When I got it back the Special function keys are mixed up.

```
F3 - mutes sound - it should do expose 
f4 - decreases volume - it should show the dashboard
f5 - increases volume ....etc,
...
F11 - expose - it should decrease volume
f12 - dashboard - it should increase volume
```

I have checked and made sure that System Preferences>Keyboard>"use all F keys as standard function keys" is not selected. And that no accessibility options are switched on either.

How do I fix this? or should I bring it back to the repair shop?

Thanks

Comment: So what exactly is the behavior? You need to press Fn but it's set to not require Fn? Or is it always like this, Fn or not?

Comment: It's not set to require fn. Even when I select that option it doesn't work properly either. The keys that have the volume pictures on them don't control volume etc. Its like the OS has mixed up the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was hardware related. An older model to was installed with a newer keyboard. I brought it to a proper Apple store and they fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has [changed the keyboard firmware](http://guides.macrumors.com/Keyboard_shortcuts#Shortcuts_on_laptops) a number of times, rearranging the function key meanings.  As far as I know, there is no way to go back to the old firmware.

It might be possible to convince [KeyRemapper4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/index.html) to rearrange them to match the keycaps; see [How to add new settings](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/document.html#t3).

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling the `System Preferences`, go to `Keyboard` (second row, `Hardware`), `Keyboard` (Tab), Toggle `Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys.`. Maybe what's internally set and what's displayed are different.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting your [PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379), if you didn't already do so.